# Python - Syntax error while using myList?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm really confused.  I've been working on the code below (and image attached)-- I keep getting a syntax error for the line `print myList[i],' ',`

I think it has to do with parenthesis but i'm not sure.  Any help is appreciated!

[image: 1]

```
def SwapFirstAndLast(list):
    temp = list[len(list)-1]
    list[len(list)-1] = list[0]
    list[0] = temp

def ReplaceEvensWithZeros(list):
     for i in range(len(list)):
      if(list[i] % 2 == 0):
       list[i] = 0

#Initializes a list with ten random integers
     import random
     myList=[]
     for i in range(10):
        myList.append(random.randrange(1,101,1))
#- every element at an even index
     for i in range(0, len(myList), 2):
      print myList[i],' ',
#- every even element
    print
    for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i] % 2 == 0:
    print myList[i],' ',
#- all elements in reverse order
    print
    print myList[::-1]
#- only the first and last element.
    print myList[-1:], ' ', myList[:1]
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up.

Comment: I bet you're running Python 3, where print is a function

Comment: The Python interpreter recognizes both spaces or tabs. I think you have mixed both spaces and tabs, pick one or the other.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes! I am.  What does that mean exactly? Thanks!

Comment: if you just read the documentation or plug your traceback into google...https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Got it! Thank you @cricket_007 !

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax error should be something like this:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

It tells you that you are not formatting your code correctly. Python uses indent to struct the code logic. Please follow the rule.

Comment: The error marker is on print, but the indentation does need fixed